# Variable references non-existent resource : ${project_loc:project_name}

Tags: java, eclipse

I downgraded from Java version 9 to Java version 8 just because I encountered an error in Eclipse and I read here that I should do that and the error would be solved. Unfortunately I encountered another problem when I uninstalled the Java version 9. I have installed Java version 8 and have added the correct folder to the JAVA_HOME system variable.

I get the following error when trying to Run my project:

```
Variable references non-existent resource : ${project_loc:bigdata}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version of Java. Do you have a project called 'bigdata'? Look in the 'Run > Run Configuration...' dialog and find your program - look for the '${project_loc:bigdata}' somewhere in the run configuration.

Comment: Somewhere in the run configuration (probably in the _Arguments_ or _Environment_ tab) the used variable `${project_loc:bigdata}` should be `${project_loc:/bigdata}` (assuming you have a project `bigdata`).

Answer (score 0):

Clean up all your compiled objects in your project directories.

1. Run -> Run As -> Maven clean
2. Restart your eclipse and Run your project again, asssuming your Java_Home variable are all correctly set.

Comment: Thanks for answering however, it is better to include a short explanation of why you think this would solve the problem. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more.